# JMETER: multipart/form-data request - unable to upload any file type using jmeter

Tags: file-upload, configuration, jmeter, multipartform-data, jmeter-5.0

*Jmeter v.5.1.1 r1855137*

I'm trying to upload **.xlsx** file using **multipart/form-data** request type,
however, I'm getting different errors such as:

- multipart body length limit 16384 exceeded;
- unexpected end of stream, the content may have already been read by another component;

---

**T**hese are parameters for **POST** request that should upload our **.xlsx** file:
[screenshot_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/el9cC.jpg)

```
Method:                            POST;
Use multipart/form-data checkbox:  unchecked;
File Path:                         C:\temp\5000Lanes.xlsx;
Parameter Name:                    file;
MIME Type:                         application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

- MIME type value is specified for .**xlsx** file types - https://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html;

---

**T**hese are **Header Manager** parameters
[screenshot_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSOvI.jpg)

```
Content-Type:                      multipart/form-data; boundary=--AaB03x
```

Note that **Body Data** and **Parameters** left empty
[screenshot_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MNcA.jpg)

---

So, please help me to figure out what is wrong in configuration to make upload successful ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 1 day of struggle I've found the solution and now the upload is successful.

---

So, using the same configs that were specified in my question
the only thing you need to add is to proceed to '**Advanced**' tab of your HTTP Request and set '**Implementation**' parameter to **Java**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtEDz.png

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header from the HTTP Header Manager
2. Tick `Use multipart/form-data` box for the HTTP Request sampler:

   [image]

Going forward be aware that you don't have to manually build file upload requests (as well as any other requests), you can record the file upload event using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), just make sure to copy the file to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation otherwise JMeter won't be able to properly catch the request and generate correct HTTP Request sampler, see [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) for more details

3. [According to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.3](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-3-released-td5728863.html) (or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) on next available opportunity